# CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point XUnit

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I have a console Application with a Main method

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Variables Initialization

            var sqlService = new SQLService();
            var ruleService = new RuleService();
            var fileService = new FileService();
            var recDetail = new ReconciliationDetails();
            List<string> ListHashesSource = null;
            List<string> ListHashesTarget = null;
            HashSet<string> HashsetSource = new HashSet<string>();
            HashSet<string> HashsetTarget = new HashSet<string>();
            HashSet<string> interceptedRows = new HashSet<string>();
            int numberOfMatchesOnSource = 0;
            int numberOfMatchesOnTarget = 0;

...
         }
```

And Im trying to install xUnit to do unit testing and integration test to my console application.

```
namespace SparkPOC.Tests
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this test doesnt appear on my test explorer window of visual studio 2019 and when I do build to my solution it throws this error:
[image]

SparkPOC.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Models\AppConfiguration.cs~RF1f4d2dd7.TMP" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ConsoleTables" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="EasyConsole" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Spark" Version="0.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="TrieNet.Core" Version="1.0.4" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

SparkPOC.Tests.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost" Version="16.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SparkPOC\SparkPOC.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I added this line

```
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
```

as suggestion in this site

https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/

Solution Structure:

[image]

My test explorer

[image]

Comment: _to do unit testing and integration test to my console application_ Why do you need to do that in the same console app? Would you mind to move it into separate project?

Comment: Currently I'm only thinking in do unit tests, but I want in the future to do a integration test because I never did and I am trying to learn it

Comment: It's not clear to me why you've specified `<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>` - your test project *doesn't* contain a Main method. I would concentrate on one problem at a time though - unload your test project and *just* get your console app working first. Once that's working, then get the test project working too.

Comment: If I unload the test project, everything works fine

Comment: Hang on - I've just noticed that your test project doesn't even reference your main project. That's very confusing. It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] here. It really should be fine.

Comment: The problem is not that, i added the reference and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate project for your unit tests. And do not declare a class with `Main` method inside this project, xUnit has already a `Main` method that it uses to run the tests.

And make sure that the "Discover tests in real time from C# ...." is checked under **Tools > Options > Test > General** 
[image]

Otherwise, you will need to click on "Run All" to discover all your tests, each time you add a new one.

Comment: Yes, I tried to reproduce your issue and apparently it's the `<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>` that was causing the error on my side. Once removed, everything is good.

Comment: Yes I removed that and it solved the error, but the test is stil not shown ion the test explorer in visual studio 2019

Comment: I've added a screenshot for the test discovery option.

Comment: I have to do what you suggested and I had to go to VS installer and install .NET Desktop development package and it worked

Comment: For those using xunit, I reverted from <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3"> to <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1"> and CS5001 error is gone